# Dereferncing Error In Java Array HW

Tags: java, arrays, dereference

I'm getting an error about dereferencing in the following code (I've commented out where it gets caught up)

The main method works fine, but the Mply method is causing me lots of headaches. Hope this is sort of clear.

```
    //multiply matrixes
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class Assignment1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      int a=5;
      int b=2;
      int x[][] = new int[a][b];
          for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<b;j++)
                x[i][j]=0;
        System.out.println(x[1][1]);
        /*
     for(int j= 0; j<                                    
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] = s.nextInt();
        */
        // read from file

        FileInputStream fstream=null;
        try{
           fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\javastuff\\principles\\input.txt");

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream))) {
                 String line;
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                   System.out.println(line);

                    /* StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                       while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                           // parse each integer in file
                           int i = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
                     System.out.println("Number " + i);
                       }
                 */




           }
           br.close();
         }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        // write to file

      BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;
       try{
         outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\javastuff\\principles\\output.txt"));

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {

            outputWriter.write(Integer.toString(x[i][0]));
            outputWriter.newLine();
        }
            outputWriter.flush();  
            outputWriter.close();

             }
         catch (Exception e){

         }

    }
    public static void Mply(int x[][], int a, int b){ //multiplies arraries and checks if they are same values
       int aRows = a.length;
        int aColumns = a[0].length;//starts dereferecning herer
        int bRows = b.length;
        int bColumns = b[0].length;

      for (int i=0; i<a; ++i)
        for (int j=0; j<b; ++j)
        for (int k=0; k<a[0][0].length(); ++k)
        x[i][k] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile...

Comment: What's the issue you're getting? Do you have any output? Any stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the method header for `Mply`

```
public static void Mply(int x[][], int a, int b)
```

The type of `x` is `int[][]`, the type of `a` is `int`, and the type of `b` is `int`. Specifically, note that `a` and `b` are **not** arrays.

Thus trying to access them as arrays by using `a[0]` is illegal.

If you want `a` and `b` to be 2-dimensional arrays, you have to update your method header to say that.

```
public static void Mply(int[][] x, int[][] a, int[][] b)
```